# how to use insert for multiple enteries in database

Tags: php, mysql

i have 8000 events in the database and i want to make this insert query for all, my current query is

```
where `event_id = 585,`
```

it should be dynamic

```
INSERT INTO 
event_site_text 
(event_id, constant_value,default_value, value, section,section_order,constant_order)
 VALUES
(585, 'REGISTER_TICKET_END', '11.49- Register Ticket End','Registration tickets are full, please contact event organizer.','Billing', '11', '49')
;
```

I know, I can achieve it using PHP `select` query and then `insert`, but can i do it using single insert query?

I want insert query automatic check in `events` table and then insert in `event_site_text` table?

---

updated:

i want when my insert query run it insert 8000 records for all the events in the database

Comment: Sorry, ur question is not clear enough, do you mean, you want to insert all the events copied from another table?

Comment: i have updated my question, sorry for my english

Comment: I think you are searching for something like: INSERT INTO event_site_text SELECT col1,col2 FROM events;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are searching for something like:

```
INSERT INTO
event_site_text 
(event_id, constant_value,default_value, value, section,section_order,constant_order)
SELECT
event_id, constant_value,default_value, value, section,section_order,constant_order
FROM
events
WHERE event_id in(585,other_id, another_id...)
;
```

ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 1):

Your example is almost there - you just need to add a comma between the records you want to insert. Unfortunately, this approach only allows you to insert up to 1000 records at a time, so you'll have to do a couple of inserts. Here's an example of a query that conveys the premise of what you're talking about (this would insert 4 records). I would suggest building the values as a string and then executing the entire SQL statement: `INSERT INTO example
VALUES
  (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
  (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
  (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
  (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');`

Comment: where from i get 100, 101, 102 values?

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you mean - this is just mock data. Do you know what records you're trying to insert or are you first trying to find the data and then insert it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert all the data from `tb_a` to `tb_b` use simple :

`INSERT IGNORE INTO table_b SELECT * FROM table_a;`